# Spring Tools 導入後に PATH の設定を行う方法を知りたい

Tags: java, macos, spring

Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse の環境構築をしています。

PATHを下記のようにしたいのですが、

```
$ echo $PATH    
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

実際にはターミナルで `echo $PATH` で確認すると下のようになります。

```
/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
```

どのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

**使用環境とバージョン**

macOS Catalina
Homebrew 2.2.13
jdk14.0.1
Maven 3.6.3_1
STS 4.6.1

Comment: どこかで PATH の設定をしているようであればその内容も質問に追記してみてください。(単に "こうなって欲しい" と思うだけで勝手に設定されるわけではないはずなので)

Comment: どこでpathの設定をするのかわからないので質問をしています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例えばログインシェルが bash の場合、エディタ等で `.bash_profile` の末尾に以下の記述を追記してください。

**参考:**
[MacにSpring Tool Suiteを導入する](https://qiita.com/segur/items/f9d7b5cdbc02531ffbb0)

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。